# EDIT php file only displays error

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a edit.php file .It seems to work but it only displays error from the echo line (end of the line). I can't seem to find where i have mistyped or have not typed in the coding.

[image: This is what it shows.]

What should I do to fix this?

```
<?php
/*
EDIT.PHP
Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/
// creates the edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

 function renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error)

{

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Edit Record</title>

  </head>

  <body>

  <?php

    // if there are any errors, display them

    if ($error != '')

    {

      echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

    }

   ?>

    <form action="" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" name="songid" value="<?php echo $songid; ?>"/>

      <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:400px;">
       <tbody>
         <tr style="text-align:center">
         <td colspan="2"><h2 style="color:#00008b;">Edit song into Music Database</h2><label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
         </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Title<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Artist<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="artist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Genre<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="genre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Language<label style="#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="language"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lyrics: <label style="#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><textarea name="lyrics" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">



 </form>

 </body>

 </html>

 <?php

  } // continue end of function of renderform 


 // connect to the database

  include('connect-db.php');


  // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))

  {

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

 if (is_numeric($_POST['songid']))

 {

 // get form data, making sure it is valid

        $songid = (isset($_POST['songid']) ? $_POST['songid'] : null);

        $title = (isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : null);
        $artist = (isset($_POST['artist']) ? $_POST['artist'] : null);
        $genre = (isset($_POST['genre']) ? $_POST['genre'] : null);
        $lyrics = (isset($_POST['lyrics']) ? $_POST['lyrics'] : null);
        $language = (isset($_POST['language']) ? $_POST['language'] : null);



   // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in

   if ($title == '' || $artist == '' || $genre == '' || $lyrics == '' || $language == '')

   {

   // generate error message

    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

   //error, display form

    renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error);

    }

   else

   {

    // save the data to the database

    mysql_query("UPDATE players SET title='$title', artist='$artist', genre='$genre', lyrics='$lyrics', language='$language' WHERE songid='$songid'")

    or die(mysql_error());

   // once saved, redirect back to the view page

    header("Location: view.php");

    }

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

 echo 'Error!';

}

 }

  else

 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
  {

  // get the 'songid' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['songid']) && is_numeric($_GET['songid']) && $_GET['songid'] > 0)

{

 // query db

 $songid = $_GET['songid'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songid=$songid")
 or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse

     if($row)

    {



        // get data from db

        $title = $row['title'];

        $artist = $row['artist'];

        $genre = $row['genre'];

        $lyrics = $row['lyrics'];

        $language= $row['language'];


        // show form

        renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error);

    }

else

    // if no match, display result

{

    echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'songid' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'songid' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Did you add the `songid` parameter in your URL? And is it a valid number (`is_numeric`) and higher than 0?

Comment: Is there any error in the console of the browser?

Comment: @Frank M Yes I did add it and yes it is higher than 0

Comment: @Singh Piyush no. The error showing is from the echo 'Error'

Comment: OMG this code. Hurts. my. eyeballs. @Zirah please try to structure and organize the code a bit more -- and it will be more immediately clear where your problems are. First of all indent it properly. Then perhaps try and get rid of that nested if-else-if blurb, you could e.g. turn the code in them into functions, so we could actually see in one look what sort of condition tree you've got going on there. This sort of (non-)structure is a nightmare to debug... happy refactoring!

Answer (score 0):

Propably you defined function but not executed. Please check it:

```
<?php
/*
EDIT.PHP
Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/
// creates the edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

renderForm();

 function renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error)

{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your first screenshot, you use `id` in the URL instead of `songid`.

Try changing `id` to `songid`, like [localhost/songdb/edit.php?songid=14](http://localhost/songdb/edit.php?songid=14)

Answer (score 0):

your code has some syntax errors but I fixed it also something to note is I tidied up your code and move some stuff around also noticed you were using MySQL when it is deprecated so I made it MySQLI and I gave you the way to connect to your database also when changing header location it is suggested that you put exit(); afterwards to stop the rest of the PHP code from running

---

```
 <?php
include('connect-db.php');
function renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error){

}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (is_numeric($_POST['songid'])){
        $songid = (isset($_POST['songid']) ? $_POST['songid'] : null);
        $title = (isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : null);
        $artist = (isset($_POST['artist']) ? $_POST['artist'] : null);
        $genre = (isset($_POST['genre']) ? $_POST['genre'] : null);
        $lyrics = (isset($_POST['lyrics']) ? $_POST['lyrics'] : null);
        $language = (isset($_POST['language']) ? $_POST['language'] : null);
        if ($title == null || $artist == null || $genre == null || $lyrics == null || $language == null){
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
        } else {
            $conn = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'DB');// This will be located in your connect.php but the refrence variable("$conn") is important if you are going to use this php
            $conn->query("UPDATE players SET '$title', artist='$artist', genre='$genre', lyrics='$lyrics', language='$language' WHERE songid='$songid''");
            header("Location: view.php");
            exit();

        }
    } else {
        $error = "Song Id is not valid";
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['songid']) && is_numeric($_GET['songid']) && $_GET['songid'] > 0){
    $songid = $_GET['songid'];
    "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songid=$songid"
    $result = $conn->query("UPDATE players SET '$title', artist='$artist', genre='$genre', lyrics='$lyrics', language='$language' WHERE songid='$songid''");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $title = $row['title'];
        $artist = $row['artist'];
        $genre = $row['genre'];
        $lyrics = $row['lyrics'];
        $language= $row['language'];
        renderForm($songid, $title, $artist, $genre, $lyrics, $language, $error); // Still not quite sure what you are doing with this function because there is no function made on this current php script

    } else {
        $error = "No results!";
    }
} else {
    $error = "Song id in URL is not valid";
}
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Edit Record</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    if ($error){
      echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
   ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="songid" value="<?php echo $songid; ?>"/>
      <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:400px;">
       <tbody>
         <tr style="text-align:center">
         <td colspan="2"><h2 style="color:#00008b;">Edit song into Music Database</h2><label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
         </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Title<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Artist<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="artist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Genre<label style="color:#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="genre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Language<label style="#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="language"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lyrics: <label style="#FF0000;"></label></td>
    <td><textarea name="lyrics" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```